# Combining XPaths / Cannot cast xs:untypedAtomic to node

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Working on a database with 30k+ files, each Fruit within a separate .xml a bit more complex than this:

```
<Fruit>
<Node1 name="papaya"><Childnode1 skincolor="YELLOW"></Childnode1></Node1>
<Node2 color="red"></Node2>
</Fruit>

<Fruit>
<Node1 name="apple"><Childnode1 skincolor="red"></Childnode1></Node1>
<Node2 color="Yellow"></Node2>
</Fruit>

<Fruit>
<Node1 name="banana"><Childnode1 skincolor="yELLOW"></Childnode1></Node1>
<Node2 color="yellow"></Node2>
</Fruit>
```

I looked for the same string in two different attributes:

`/Fruit/Node1/Childnode1[matches(@skincolor,'yellow','i')/data(Fruit/Node1/@name)
/Fruit/Node2[matches(@color,'yellow','i')]/data(Fruit/Node1/@name)`

Some results are duplicates (only banana in this example), so I tried to rewrite both paths into a single expression:

`/Fruit/Node1/Childnode1[matches(@skincolor,'yellow','i')/data(Fruit/@name)
|
/Fruit/Node2[matches(@color,'yellow','i')]/data(Fruit/@name)`

There was an error: "Cannot cast xs:untypedAtomic to node()". My intention was to combine them and then keep only distinct values.
I'm new to XML/programming/SO, so please explain like I'm 5 (and learning to code).

Comment: Please note that your first XPath is invalid. It would be helpful for your readers if you checked your queries before submitting them to Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry for the mixup. my laptop was in a bad state, so much that simple queries were taking half an hour. will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union operator applies only to sets/sequences of nodes, but an expression that calls the data() function returns sequences of atomic values.

Your original path expressions are wrong anyway. If we add the missing "]", you have

`/Fruit/Node1/Childnode1[matches(@skincolor,'yellow','i')]/data(Fruit/@name)`

which will not select anything because the context item for `Fruit/@name` is a `Childnode1` element, which does not have a `Fruit` child. It should be, for example

`/Fruit[Node1/Childnode1[matches(@skincolor,'yellow','i')]]/data(@name)`

To eliminate duplicates you need to consider what exactly you mean by duplicates. If you have two different `Fruit` elements, both with `@name="banana"`, do you want to treat them as duplicates or not? If the situation doesn't arise then you can go either way. If by duplicates you mean "both expressions select the same Fruit element", then you can use the union operator "|" to eliminate duplicates. If you mean "both expressions select Fruit elements with the same value for @name", then you should use distinct-values().

Comment: only now realizing why there were no results when they are expected. my original xpath had the closing ], but your corrected xpath did the trick. and indeed I have distinct entries with the same value for @name. will use union operator. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The function fn:distinct-values can be used for that:

```
distinct-values(/Fruit/(
  Node1/Childnode1[matches(@skincolor,'yellow','i')],
  Node2[matches(@color,'yellow','i')]
)/Fruit/@name)
```

Comment: corrected the xpath resulted in no hits, because my expressions were selecting the wrong level. thanks nonetheless.